C# .net and Mysql insert statement fails during command execution
I am trying to insert into the mysql database the following record in a Create() method in a Repository class:
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `documentdetails` (?dtoDocumentId);", _connection);

command.Connection = _connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    
command.Parameters.Add("?dtoDocumentId", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value=documentDetail.DocumentId;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

The documentId is a BigInt datatype which is retrieved from the documentDetails DTO which is of datatype long.
The DocumentDetails table has 2 fields: Id (auto increments) and DocumentId whcih is what I am trying to insert in the code.
When calling the API endpoint which is associated with the above Create() method, the following errors are raised in the logs:

2024-04-09 10:27:06.106 +03:00 [ERR] Fatal error encountered during
command execution. 2024-04-09 10:27:06.109 +03:00 [ERR]    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior
behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior
behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(Boolean
execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
DocumentProcessing.Database.Repositories.DocumentDetailsRepository.CreateUpdateDocumentDetail(DocumentDetailDTO
documentDetailDTO) in
C:\Users\source\repos\DocumentProcessing\Database\Repositories\DocumentDetailsRepository.cs:line
123
2024-04-09 10:27:06.111 +03:00 [ERR] Fatal error encountered
attempting to read the resultset. 2024-04-09 10:27:06.113 +03:00 [ERR]
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResultAsync(Boolean
execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior
behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-04-09 10:27:06.114 +03:00 [ERR] Reading from the stream has
failed.
2024-04-09 10:27:06.115 +03:00 [ERR]    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacketAsync(Boolean execAsync)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacketAsync(Boolean
execAsync)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResultAsync(Int32 affectedRow,
Int64 insertedId, Boolean execAsync)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResultAsync(Int32 statementId, Int32
affectedRows, Int64 insertedId, Boolean execAsync)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResultAsync(Int32 statementId,
Boolean force, Boolean execAsync)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResultAsync(Boolean
execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-04-09 10:27:06.117 +03:00 [ERR] Unable to read data from the transport
connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
2024-04-09 10:27:06.118 +03:00 [ERR]    at
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
Int32 count)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.ReadAsync(Byte[]
buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean execAsync)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
Int32 count)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFullyAsync(Stream stream,
Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean execAsync)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacketAsync(Boolean execAsync)
2024-04-09 10:27:06.119 +03:00 [ERR] A connection attempt failed
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
time, or established connection failed because connected host has
failed to respond. 2024-04-09 10:27:06.120 +03:00 [ERR]    at
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
Int32 count)
2024-04-09 10:27:06.121 +03:00 [DBG]
UnitOfWork:SaveChanges 2024-04-09 10:27:06.122 +03:00 [ERR] Connection
must be valid and open to commit transaction
2024-04-09 10:27:06.123 +03:00 [ERR]    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.CommitAsync(Boolean execAsync,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Commit()    at
DocumentProcessing.Database.Repositories.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges() in
C:\Users\source\repos\DocumentProcessing\Database\Repositories\UnitOfWork.cs:line
64

After some investigation, I found out that when calling the create API endpoint using Postman (with documentID=1165078) the record gets created successfully. However when I do this programmatically and the documentID is assigned through code processing, the above errors are raised in the logs. Could this be an error related to the documentId datatype and the datatype of the database? Could you please help me understand how to fix this?
Could you please tell me why would
command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO `DocumentDetails` (DocumentId) VALUES ({0});", documentDetail.DocumentId); 
would fail and
command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO `DocumentDetails` (DocumentId) VALUES ({0});", 1165078); 
would succeed please?
Many thanks,

"Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction" - is the connection open? is it already being used by another operation?

Hi Marc! thank you for the prompt feedback. Yes the connection is open, the error related to the connection is raised after the Create() method is executed, in the SaveChanges() method which is used to commit the changes to the database.

Managed to identify the root cause of the issue, it was a logic bug. The reason the insert command was failing is because the documentDetail.DocumentID was holding an ID which was created but not committed to the database yet. Therefore due to the fact that DocumentDetails had a foreign key to a not-created ID yet, it was failing during command execution. Maybe this will help someone in the future.
Many thanks everyone

Remember always close() your connection
command.Connection.Close();

Could you please tell me why would command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO DocumentDetails (DocumentId) VALUES ({0});", documentDetail.DocumentId); would fail and
command.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO DocumentDetails (DocumentId) VALUES ({0});", 1165078); would succeed please?
